# Install Windows 10 on SSD through SATA to USB?

Tags: windows-10, usb, ssd

I am stuck with a weird problem here. I am trying to install Windows 10 on an "old" Windows 7 desktop machine for a friend. I purchased an SSD for him, but when I try to install Windows through USB it says:

> We couldn't create a new partition or locate an existing one. For more information, see the Setup log files

I have tried:

- Converting the drive to MBR and GPT
- Diskpart -> clean -> create new primary partition -> mark as active
- Remove all CD, SD, etc. drives from the motherboard (they don't appear in BIOS)
- New SATA cable
- Plug SSD into USB adapter and partition the drive on my desktop and mark it as active

However, none of these worked out for me. Very weird. Therefore I want to install Windows on the SSD through USB through my PC. I have a couple of SATA to USB adapters (with power and everything), so the drive basically appears as an USB drive in Windows. How would I go on about installing my Windows ISO on this drive through USB, without screwing up my partitions on my desktop PC?

What I have:

- Windows ISO
- USB adapter to hook up the SSD to my desktop

Let me know what the best approach would be, to solve this issue would be. Thanks!

Comment: What’s the rationale behind this whole undertaking? Is the laptop not capable of booting from USB, so you could create a thumb drive containing Windows Setup?

Comment: Why don't you just clone the existing install to the SSD, swap drives, deal with re-authenticating at MS, then do a regular upgrade.

Comment: @DanielB Read the post again. I get the error "We couldn't create a new partition or locate an existing one. For more information, see the Setup log files" and I have tried basically everything to make the new SSD and old HDD work.

Comment: @Tetsujin Because the old HDD has been erased. I need to start from scratch.

Comment: Then the description 'old Win7 machine' is incorrect - right now it's just 'a machine' ;) If you can force an OS onto a USB drive [difficult as you need an Enterprise license to be able to install WinToGo] then it would very likely fail to boot when you put it back in the first machine, unless you have something like Acronis Universal Restore, which can 'de-specify' a boot drive. How did you generate your 'Windows ISO'? Media Creator?

Comment: @Tetsujin I just need to install Windows 10 on the SSD partition, which I have plugged into my desktop through USB. Would loading the ISO through VMWare (or another virtual machine manager) work? As long as I select the SSD as the target drive

Comment: Windows is not designed to run from an external USB, so it won't install to one, without WinToGo & an Enterprise license. You are making this very much an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info)

Comment: @Tetsujin It seems like the most rational solution. If you think you have a better solution, then please let me know. I have been stuck here trying to do this for over 10 hours so far. I have tried everything I could find on Google.

Comment: I'm on the edge of thinking this might be a motherboard problem, even though the old HDD won't even work now (it worked fine before I decided to reinstall Windows). Reflashing BIOS firmware might help, but I'm not sure...

Comment: Trying Windows 7 installation from USB now. I did try both 32-bit and 64-bit Windows 10, but maybe it's just a problem with Windows 10. I've tried a pirated version (just the ISO) and MSDN Windows 10, no luck so far. Hopefully Windows 7 works.

Comment: Will any other OS install without the partition error?

Comment: Usually this error is because there is more than one drive or storage device present and windows setup chose one (or can only see that one for some reason) that cannot be used for OS install....http://robertgreiner.com/2015/08/windows-10-couldnt-create-a-new-partition/

Comment: @Moab I am currently trying Windows 7. I'll report back asap after that. I have unplugged literally everything except one SATA cable, which goes to the SSD. The SSD and my USB stick is the ONLY things showing in the BIOS.

Comment: @Moab Windows 7 did not work neither. I got the same message as before.

Comment: Does the PC have a card reader?

Comment: @Moab Unplugged but yes it does. It has been unplugged completely from the motherboard.

Answer (score 0):

Worked by using another USB drive. In this case an SD card actually. I had to plug in an USB drive as well (with the same Windows ISO installed), because the installer apparently couldn't find some of the media on the SD card.

TL;DR: Use another USB drive and you won't waste 8+ hours on something stupid.

Comment: I have experienced this problem before as well. Specifically with Kingston drives. After encountering the issue with 4 of their drives, I always use another brand and the issue has never reoccurred.

Comment: You can accept your own answer: [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) Without an accepted answer, the system will keep bumping your question to the home page (unless the question gets downvoted).

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you resolved your issue already, but I was able to install Windows 10 (Home and Pro) on a removable drive through a VM. I had initially tried installing Windows directly, but the installer was not able to find the drive.

Set the USB SSD as a physical disk in your VM software and the Windows installer should have no trouble installing to it.

It's been a while since I've done it, but here's a rundown of my setup (to the best of my memory).

Hardware:

- Laptop (Lenovo L380 Yoga) running Fedora (31 I think)
- SSD in [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B079239K1N) enclosure. I had a 128 GB msata drive inside it.
- VirtualBox (using [these](https://www.serverwatch.com/server-tutorials/using-a-physical-hard-drive-with-a-virtualbox-vm.html) instructions to configure VirtualBox to use the physical drive. The instructions basically creates a virtual disk file that links to your physical drive.

For reference, here is the command to create a create a virtual disk file that links to your removable drive:

- Linux: `VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename "</path/to/file>.vmdk" -rawdisk /dev/(DRIVE)`
- Windows: `VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename "C:\Users\<user_name>\VirtualBox VMs\<VM_folder_name>\<file_name>.vmdk" -rawdisk \\.\PhysicalDrive#`
- Mac: `VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename "</path/to/file>.vmdk" -rawdisk /dev/disk#`

My host machine ran Linux, so I used the Linux command.

When booting `windows.iso` in virtualbox, I ran into no issues when installing to the drive. The vm cannot access the Windows key contained on my drive, so I was asked for verification. I had previously linked my Windows key to my Microsoft account, so I think I just used my Microsoft credentials to activate Windows (on first boot).

After installing, I was able to boot directly off the removable SSD without any issues (directly meaning bare-metal). Note that I only booted this drive on my host machine (the lenovo laptop).

Hope this helps anyone in the future.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted, it’s a fine answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Windows and Linux system on hand, it is easy.
Use Rufus for Windows. Look it up and download it. then use Windows and Rufus to make a Win-to-Go disk on a thumb drive and then go to Linux and use  DD  to copy the thumb drive to the target USB to SATA drive. In Linux for example /DEV/SDX1 is source drive (The win to go USB you just made) and /DEV/SDX2 is target drive, the usb to sata drive. Linux command "  DD BS=32768 if=/dev/sdx1 of=/dev/sdx2/ status=progress  " IF = input file (The source drive or file ) and OF=output (target drive or file). Then boot off the USB to SATA drive you just wrote to and continue the install just like a Win-to-Go install. DD is also known as Disk Destroyer so I always use Gparted (a Linux disk partitioning tool I highly recommend) to confirm source and destination drives of the read and write. A wrong "of" which means "output file" or disk drive, can wipe an entire drive including a boot drive. BE VERY CAREFUL with DD!
I have used new usb to  sata drives to make some my of old computers like my Winstick and old tablets a lot faster. It is a major improvement.  But you cannot install Windows on a USB for some odd reason. Windows sucks Linux Rules!!  I gotta use Windows for games though.